# Как вычислить математическое выражение из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, калькулятор, python-faq

```
if message.startswith("!число"):
    split = message.split(' ', 1)
    a = []
    b = []
    plus = split[1].split('+')
    a.append(plus[0])
    b.append(plus[1])
    print(int(a[0]) + int(b[0]))
```

Вот так я сделал операцию сложения. Пользователь пишет в чат команду !число 5+5 и бот отвечает 10. Но если пользователь напишет там - или * или /, то программа выдаст ошибку, как можно сделать это лучше, что бы пользователь мог сделать любую арифметическую операцию?

Comment: Я немного углубился в ваш код и у меня возник вопрос , а работает ли у вас сложение с двузначными и трёхзначными числами?

Comment: Да, всё работает

Comment: Можно регуляркой найти нужные подстроки

Comment: `pip install numexpr` -> `numexpr.evaluate(expr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю вам калькулятор из сторонней библиотеки.

Использовать калькулятор так:

```
# pip install simpleeval
from simpleeval import simple_eval

...

if message.startswith("!число"):
    _, math_str = message.split(' ', 1)
    result = simple_eval(math_str)
    print(result)
```

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8ef8449e97330c0b78e10ee04ea57a6592a0d28a/calculator/use__simpleeval__module.py) калькулятора через [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
from simpleeval import simple_eval

print(simple_eval("21 + 21"))  # 42
print(simple_eval("2 + 2 * 2"))  # 6
print(simple_eval("21 + 19 / 7 + (8 % 3) ** 9"))  # 535.7142857142857
print(simple_eval("square(11)", functions={"square": lambda x: x * x}))  # 121
```

---

**PS.**

[Еще примеры калькуляторов, среди них есть и те, что не нужно будет устанавливать](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/8ef8449e97330c0b78e10ee04ea57a6592a0d28a/calculator)

Comment: Странный калькулятор который даёт возможность вставить код, на подобии примера из статьи хабр. Понятно если запрещать нож только потому что он является опасным предметом. Тогда почему есть eval и ножи? Ради забавы? Думаю нет. Я не писал что eval безопасная функция. Но не вижу опасности в использовании его вместо калькулятора именно калькулятора а не компьютера где возможен произвольный ввод.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, я бы eval сравнил не с ножом, а с пушкой, а их после проверки и предварительной подготовки выдают :) eval безопасен при выполнении кода самого программиста, т.е. то, что заранее было написано, но не то, что может прийти от любого пользователя. Понятно, что можно поставить больше проверок, но всегда останется возможность что останется дыра в безопасности. Кст, пример использования eval (и exec, как его ближайшей аналогии) в `dataclasses` (функция `_process_class`), а еще в `collections.namedtuple` (функция `namedtuple`)

Comment: @AzizUmarov, и если что, минус вам не я поставил (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prr7D.png) ;) Когда ставишь минус, рейтинг уменьшается, вчера у вас было 6061, а сегодня 6060, плюс время когда моему ответу минус поставили и время вашего комментария совпадает :) Если я ошибся и это не вы, то извиняюсь за подозрение, хех

Comment: На любой хитрый eval() найдется свой пентестер с винтом.

Comment: А я что скрыл или хотел утаить минус? Я написал что есть стандартная функция eval именно стандартная. А вы предлагаете третью библиотеку и говорите что играть с огнем опасно

Comment: На счёт execute и прочих. Пишите варианты а не говорите о том что в руках обезъяны граната представляет опасность. Автору нужен калькулятор. И если он позволит убить этим сервер или планету вовсе то пусть идёт лесом

Comment: @AzizUmarov, я хотел указать на то, что вы незаслуженно моему ответу поставили минус, т.к. наверное подумали что я после свое комментария поставил его вашему, и я считаю, что ваше предложение просто использовать `eval` неправильно. Человеку нужно объяснить, что это волшебная функция имеет конкретные минусы, а вы этого **не указывали** в ответе. Автору нужен калькулятор, а он получит дыру в приложении, в которой можно выполнить любой код извне, и которую ему же латать, и простое закрытие приложения как это `eval('__import__("sys").exit()')` самое меньшее из проблем

Comment: @gil9red если вы считаете не заслужено я отзову свой минус если это столь критично для вас. Я добавил в свой ответ пояснений почему не стоит использовать третьи библиотеки для простой арифметической операции когда можно использовать RegEx и eval.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, ок, теперь, я считаю, ваш ответ выглядит хорошим

Answer (score 3):

Калькуляторы - вещь весёлая, заманчиво "простая", и, на проверку, *очень глубокая*. По сути - первый шаг в мир *компиляторов и парсеров*.

Есть много вариантов, как распарсить выражение и вычислить его, много разных грамматик и видов парсеров (LL, LR, PEG, etc.).

Этот процесс обычно состоит из нескольких этапов:

1. Разбор на лексемы
2. Построение дерева парсинга
3. Построение абстрактного синтаксического дерева (из кусков текста выражения)
4. Построение конкретного синтаксического дерева (из самописных объектов операций и числовых объектов)
5. Вычисление, обходом конкретного синтаксического дерева

Написание и отладка кода, реализующего этот процесс, могут занять приличное время, но он этого зависит, как гибко ты сможешь расширять грамматику.

Однако, если ограничиваться простыми операциями, тебе **не нужен полноценный парсинг** - достаточно будет обойтись "упрощенным" вариантом, в котором смешаны сразу и парсинг, и построение дерева, и вычисление. Такой подход усложняет процесс расширения грамматики, однако не перегружает код лишними описаниями и позволяет, написав несколько функций, реализовать вычисление выражений.

Для написания примера такого упрощенного парсера-калькулятора создадим простую грамматику и напишем для неё функции-парсеры.

```py
# num -> /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/
# group -> ( term )
# value -> num | group
# mul -> num [*/] mul
# mul -> num
# sum -> mul [+-] sum
# sum -> mul
# term -> sum

import re


def num(expr):
    expr = expr.lstrip()
    res = re.match("^[+-]?\d(\.\d+)?", expr)
    if res:
        return float(res.group(0)), expr[res.end():]
    else:
        return None, expr

def value(expr):
    res, rest = num(expr)
    if res != None:
        return res, rest
    res, rest = grouping(expr)
    return res, rest

def grouping(expr):
    expr = expr.lstrip()
    rest = ""
    if expr[0] == "(":
        rest = expr[1:]
    else:
        return None, expr
    numb, rest = term(rest)
    if rest[0] != ")":
        return None, expr
    return numb, rest[1:]

def mul_oper(expr):
    expr = expr.lstrip()
    res = re.match("[*/]", expr)
    if res:
        return res.group(0), expr[res.end():]
    else:
        return None, expr

def mul(expr):
    numb1, rest1 = value(expr)

    if numb1 == None:
        return None, expr

    op, rest2 = mul_oper(rest1)

    if op == None:
        return numb1, rest1

    numb2, rest2 = mul(rest2)

    if op == "*":
        return numb1 * numb2, rest2
    if op == "/":
        return numb1 / numb2, rest2

    return None, expr

def sum_oper(expr):
    expr = expr.lstrip()
    res = re.match("[+-]", expr)
    if res:
        return res.group(0), expr[res.end():]
    else:
        return None, expr

def sum(expr):
    numb1, rest1 = mul(expr)

    if numb1 == None:
        return None, expr

    op, rest2 = sum_oper(rest1)

    if op == None:
        return numb1, rest1

    numb2, rest2 = sum(rest2)

    if op == "+":
        return numb1 + numb2, rest2
    if op == "-":
        return numb1 - numb2, rest2

    return None, expr

def term(expr):
    return sum(expr)

print(term("(2 + 2) * 2"))
```

Здесь функция `term()` занимается разбором выражения целиком, функции `sum()` и `mul()` - разбором выражений сложения/вычитания и умножения/деления **с учетом приоритета**, функция `grouping()` занимается разбором выражений в скобках, а `num()` - разбором чисел. Это урезанная реализация **PEG**.

После прохождения каждой функции изменяется не только получаемый результат, но и состояние парсера (переменная `rest`). В случае, если одна из ветвей парсинга провалилась (не был встречен ожидаемый символ), мы по цепочке подымимся до ближайшей альтернативы (*backtracking*). Это можно увидеть в работе функции `value()`, а так же (хоть и скрыто) в функциях `mul()` и `sum()`.

---

Можно написать и **чуть более прокаченный** вариант с чуть большим погружением в **PEG**. Отличия будут заключаться в следующем:

1. Будут добавлены новые функции для построения грамматики: две терминальные и три нетерминальные (комбинаторы, их видов больше, но нам хватит и трёх).
2. Правила, написанные "вручную" будут переписаны как комбинация более простых правил
3. Логика выбора пути разбора будет перенесена в комбинаторы

Терминалы:

1. **Токен** - строгое совпадение набора символов - `token()`
2. **Регулярное** выражение - совпадение по шаблону - `rexpr()`

Комбинаторы:

1. **Последовательность** (или конкатенация) - `serial()`
2. **Альтернатива** - `alternative()`
3. **Optional** - независимо от удачного парсинга возвращает удачу (удача или неудача отличается состоянием переменной `rest`) - `optional()`

```py
import re

def GN(func, *args):
    def exec(text: str):
        return func(text, *args)
    return exec

def token(text: str, token_text: str):
    if text.startswith(token_text):
        return token_text, text[len(token_text):]
    return None, text

def rexpr(text: str, regex: str):
    text = text.lstrip()
    res = re.match(regex, text)
    if res:
        return res.group(0), text[res.end():]
    else:
        return None, text

def serial(text, *funcs):
    res, rest = [], text
    for func in funcs:
        resd, restd = func(rest)
        if resd is None:
            return None, text
        res.append(resd)
        rest = restd
    if len(res) == 0:
        return None, text
    return res, rest

def alternative(text, *funcs):
    for func in funcs:
        res, rest = func(text)
        if res is not None:
            return res, rest
    return None, text

def optional(text, func):
    res, rest = func(text)
    return [res], rest

def num(expr):
    res, rest = rexpr(expr, r"^[+-]?\d(\.\d+)?")
    if res is not None:
        return float(res), rest
    return res, rest

def value(expr):
    sign = GN(rexpr, r"[+-]")
    maybe_sign = GN(optional,  sign)
    val = GN(alternative, num, grouping)
    res, rest = serial(expr, maybe_sign, val)

    if res is None:
        return None, expr

    numb = res[1]
    if res[0][0] == "-":
        return -numb, rest
    return numb, rest

def grouping(expr):
    opened_bracket = GN(token, "(")  # token(text, "(")
    closed_bracket = GN(token, ")")  # token(text, ")")

    res, rest = serial(expr, opened_bracket, term, closed_bracket)

    if res is None:
        return None, expr
    return res[1], rest

def mul(expr):
    full_expr = GN(serial, value, GN(rexpr, r"[*/]"), mul)
    res, rest = alternative(expr, full_expr, value)

    if res is None:
        return None, expr

    if isinstance(res, float):
        return res, rest

    numb1 = res[0]
    op = res[1]
    numb2 = res[2]

    if op == "*":
        return numb1 * numb2, rest
    if op == "/":
        return numb1 / numb2, rest

    return None, expr

def sum(expr):
    full_expr = GN(serial, mul, GN(rexpr, r"[+-]"), sum)
    res, rest = alternative(expr, full_expr, mul)

    if res is None:
        return None, expr

    if isinstance(res, float):
        return res, rest

    numb1 = res[0]
    op = res[1]
    numb2 = res[2]

    if op == "+":
        return numb1 + numb2, rest
    if op == "-":
        return numb1 - numb2, rest

    return None, expr

def term(expr):
    return sum(expr)


print(term("2 + 2 * 2"))
```

Для того, чтобы комбинаторы работали как надо, необходим общий интерфейс. При написании в ООП стиле достаточно создать для каждого объекта правила метод `execute(text: str)`. Однако для функций такой интерфейс необходимо создать отдельно: каждая функция помимо текста принимает и другие параметры, такие как, например, правила для rexpr или функции для serial.

Функция `GN(rule, \*args)` создаёт такую обёртку, возвращая функцию `text: str -> Union[Tuple[None, str], Tuple[float, str]]`

Comment: Мне понравился [этот вариант через ast разбора выражения](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8ef8449e97330c0b78e10ee04ea57a6592a0d28a/calculator/use__ast_parse_eval.py) калькулятора. ast делает всю грязную разботу :)

Comment: @gil9red так это то же самое. Разница только в том, что решение находится не "за один шаг", как у меня, а "за два". Как я писал выше, процесс вычисления такого выражения можно разбить на этапы. У тебя их два: построить Абстрактное Синтаксическое Дерево (оно же AST), пройтись по нему функцией-визитором и построить конкретное с.д. (оно же CST). "По-хорошему" вычисление должно проводиться обходом по CST отдельной функцией. Но в силу упрощения CST вычисляется сразу и на выходе получаем уже результат. По сути, функции по типу **op_add()** и **op_mul()** - ноды CST. Если их сделать классами.

Answer (score 1):

Ребята вы изобретаете велосипед при чем не самым лучшим образом.

Воспользуйтесь функцией [eval()](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-eval-built-in-function-601f87db191#:%7E:text=Answer%3A%20eval%20is%20a%20built,the%20result%20as%20an%20integer.)
благо есть такая.

UPD. в целях дальнейшего улучшения ответа.

Функция eval() действительно является опасной если давать ей что угодно. Статей и публикаций можно найти не мало. Но я всё же хотел бы акцентировать внимание на то что вы программист и дозволительное пользователям всё в ваших руках. Говорить что не существует безопасного сценария использования eval(), я считаю не аргументированным поскольку дать прямой доступ к eval() из приложения это как дать обезьяне гранату. Дать гранату можно преждевременно обезвредив и убедившись в безопасности данного мероприятия.

PS Элементарно требуйте ввода строго арифметического выражения: цифры и операторы (/*-+). Просто не пойму почему для данного мероприятия нужно подключать третью библиотеку и прочее. Решается простым RegEx для валидации выражения, никаких функций, вызовов, обращения к переменным и прочей ереси.

Функции под eval можно ограничить. Например, будет доступна только abs

```
eval('abs(-3)', {"__builtins__":{"abs":abs}})
```

, но другие функции можно будет достать по ссылке:

```
 eval('abs.__self__.bin(1)', {"__builtins__":{'abs':abs}})
```

Валидация для eval необходима, даже если убрать все функции и останутся только операторы.

Comment: Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--

Comment: Да конечно, пользоваться не значит не проверять

Comment: Использование `eval` с кодом извне плохая идея :) https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/ Для калькулятора лучше другое использовать, моя небольшая коллекция: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/8ef8449e97330c0b78e10ee04ea57a6592a0d28a/calculator

Comment: Странный калькулятор который даёт возможность вставить код, на подобии примера из статьи хабр. Понятно если запрещать нож только потому что он является опасным предметом. Тогда почему есть eval и ножи? Ради забавы? Думаю нет. Я не писал что eval безопасная функция. Но не вижу опасности в использовании его вместо калькулятора именно калькулятора а не компьютера где возможен произвольный ввод.

Comment: Тут именно и возможен произвольный ввод.

Comment: Тогда через eval можно получить доступ к внутренностям бота, исполнить произвольный код, и да, например, дропнуть всё.

Comment: Слушайте люди. Если вы будете делать что угодно. То данная функция позволит вам это сделать. Она не предназначена для кривых рук и тупиц разного рода. Почему с калькулятора можно ввести дроп всё? Вы все с луны попадали?

Comment: @MaxLevs, если заменить `__` на `~~` то внутренности бота в безопасности)

Comment: @eri благодарю за дополнения.

Comment: @eri  `__`? `~~`? Ты о чём?

Comment: @MaxLevs вот смотрите... Закрываем глобалс и билтингс (добавил вответ) - опасные функции теперь можно дернуть только через `__self__` и прочую магию. Заменив `__` Вы получите синтакс эррор на попытки достать чтото полезное из объектов

Comment: @eri А! Ты про фильтрацию. А я пытаюсь вспомнить, откуда в Pytuhon `~~self~~`

Comment: @MaxLevs можно просто `_` запретить,