# python: парсинг запросов с заданным словарем

Tags: python, парсер, словари, библиотеки, дерево

есть текстовая строка типа

```
text = "my-data='ab\"c x\'yz' AND (param1=123 OR param2='test')"
```

хотелось бы ее корректно распарсить

1. минимум получить значение по полю (т.е. на выходе после парсинга есть какой-нибудь словарь с ключами и значениями
2. получить и логику (т.е. после парсинга будет некоторое дерево где AND OR и скобки - это узлы)

подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь хорошие библиотеки для решения данных задач, потому что писать свой код не очень удобно (сложная логика, многих вещей сразу не учесть и т.д.)

Comment: Это некорректная строка, внимательней на кавычки

Comment: @Timofey Да нет, строка корректная, смотрите на самые внешние кавычки )  Остальные кавычки либо другого вида, либо экранированы

Comment: Интересная тема, мне тоже по работе такое может понадобится, но я пока только какой-то промежуточный формат с жёстко зашитыми правилами использую. Было бы удобно, если бы прям что-то такое можно было обрабатывать.

Comment: @CrazyElf формально она корректна (с точки зрения Python), но в итоге экранированные апострофы в обычные превращаются. Получается что эта строка эквивалентна `"my-data='ab\"c x'yz' AND (param1=123 OR param2='test')"`, и нормально не распарсится из-за `'ab\"c x'yz'`. Нужно слеши экранировать, либо сделать r-строкой.

Comment: Как вариант - превратить в корректный python код, потом распарсить с помощью ast.parse

Comment: @insolor, хорошо, есть не брать в расчет кавычки, то ast.parse подойдет как для 1) так и для 2) задач?

Comment: @Zhihar для 1 можно eval использовать, если там гарантированно не будет небезопасных данных. Ну или поискать безопасный вариант реализации eval, возможно simple_eval подойдет, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1166509/1365

Comment: @isolator в том то и дело, что не хотелось бы исполнять - мало ли что там, могут быть и опасные данные, кроме того если это переводится в python, то и с названием переменных типа `my-code` могут быть проблемы :(, я то думал про библиотеку которая хотя бы сможет в виде словаря дать соответствие между названием переменной и ее содержимым записанным в строке (пусть даже пока без логики AND или скобок ())

Comment: @Zhihar "изолятором" меня раньше называли вроде только в испанском сегменте в варианте Isolador)

Answer (score 3):

Один из хороших вариантов, это создать свой парсер используя [библиотеки](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) для построения парсеров.

Вот пример с использованием [lark](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/) для (почти) вашего случая:

```
from lark import Lark, Tree

parser = Lark(
    """
?start: expr
?expr: or_test

?or_test: (or_test "or"i)? and_test
?and_test: (and_test "and"i)? cond
?cond: VAR "=" const | "(" expr ")"

?const: INT -> int
      | string_raw -> string

?string_raw: STRING
STRING : /'[^']*'/

VAR: (NAME "-")? NAME

%import common.CNAME -> NAME
%import common.WS_INLINE
%import common.INT
%ignore WS_INLINE
""",
)


def print_tree(t, level=0):
    if type(t) == Tree:
        print(level * "  " + t.data)
        for c in t.children:
            print_tree(c, level=level + 1)
    else:
        print(level * "  " + str(t))


print_tree(parser.parse("my-data='abc\"' AND (param1=123 OR param2='test')"))
```

Такой простой парсер на выходе дает такое дерево:

```
and_test
  cond
    my-data
    string
      'abc"'
  or_test
    cond
      param1
      int
        123
    cond
      param2
      string
        'test'
```

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что логика скобок и кавычек дается "из коробки", а связки (and or xor near и т.д.) я реализую сам, а парсеру просто объясняю, что это служебные слова?

Comment: Нет. Из коробки используются некоторые правила, например, что такое INT (`%import common.INT`) или идентификатор (`CNAME`). Скобки реализованы правилом `?cond: VAR "=" const | "(" expr ")"`. Кавычки тоже самодельные - правило `STRING : /'[^']*'/`, т.е. все между одинарными кавычками кроме самой одинарной кавычки. Парсеру вы задаете правила грамматики, т.е. как последовательность символов распарсить на токены (все правила с большой буквы) и как токены упорядочить в дерево (все остальные правила). Если возникают такие вопросы нужно почитать про то, как парсеры работают. На пальцах не объяснить